# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am getting following error while running spring application. Please I need some help to resolve this or I will appreciate it if someone can tell me how I can approach to debug and resolve this issue. I am just going through Internet and doing different combinations in my pom.xml file.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1716) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:499) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar:2.0.0.M3]
    at ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.main(NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:358) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1776) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ca.naijaconnects</groupId>
    <artifactId>naijaconnectsProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>naijaconnectsProject</name>
    <description>none</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding
         >
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>

   </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

    </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot- 
   starter-data-jpa -->
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
     <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-release</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


    </project>
```

This is my run application

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class NaijaconnectsProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext factory = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        SpringApplication.run(NaijaconnectsProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my configuration file

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity.UserLoginDetails;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig 
{
    @Bean
    public UserLoginDetails userLoginDetails()
    {
        return new UserLoginDetails();
    }

}
```

This is my controller

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity.UserLoginDetails;
import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo.UserLoginRepo;
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/testing")
public class NaijaConnectsController 
{
    @Autowired
    UserLoginRepo userLoginRepo;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insertLogins", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody List<UserLoginDetails> PostFormDataJSONArray() {   
        UserLoginDetails userLoginDetail = new UserLoginDetails();
        userLoginDetail.setUserName("timisenco");
        userLoginDetail.setUserPassword("Test@2017");
        return (List<UserLoginDetails>) userLoginRepo.save(userLoginDetail);
    }

}
```

This is my entity

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@Entity
//@Table(name = "userlogindetails")
public class UserLoginDetails 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false,columnDefinition="varchar2(40)")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "USER_Pawword", nullable = false,columnDefinition="varchar2(40)")
    private String userPassword;


    public UserLoginDetails()
    {

    }
    @Bean
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }
    @Bean
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    @Bean
    public String getUserPassword()
    {
        return userPassword;
    }
    @Bean
    public void setUserPassword(String userPasword)
    {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
}
```

This is the repo

```
package ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.repo;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ca.naijaconnects.naijaconnectsproject.entity.UserLoginDetails;

@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource(exported=false)

public interface UserLoginRepo extends JpaRepository<UserLoginDetails, String>
{

    //UserLoginDetails findOne(String);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    UserLoginDetails save(UserLoginDetails account);
    //UserLoginDetails findByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress);
}
```

**EDIT**

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/naijaconnectsdb
spring.datasource.username=naijaConnects
spring.datasource.password=Connects@2017
spring.datasource.name=naijaconnectsdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=null
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 3):

Well this one is the reason:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

In a `Spring Boot` application there usually exists an `application.properties` file. There you should have declared the dialect hibernate should use and in your case you have configured: `org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect`. I believe there is a typo there, it should be `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` (the Y in MYSQL.. should be lowercase).

Can you post also your *.properties file?

So in your `application.properties` file:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

**UPDATE**
I edited your application properties file to the following:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/naijaconnectsdb 
spring.datasource.username=naijaConnects 
spring.datasource.password=Connects@2017 
spring.datasource.name=naijaconnectsdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=null 
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.Impro‌​vedNamingStrategy 
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dia‌​lect
```

Comment: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/naijaconnectsdb
spring.datasource.username=naijaConnects
spring.datasource.password=Connects@2017
spring.datasource.name=naijaconnectsdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=null
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect

Comment: I added this line spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  but still showing the same error

Comment: Same error with `MYSQL5Dialect` or with `MySQL5Dialect`?

Comment: with mySQL5Dialet

Comment: Well `mySQL5Dialet` is totally written wrong! Pay attention to uppercase/lowercase and it is missing the `c` character in `Dialect`. Please be precise.

Comment: Also noticed that in your `application.properties` file you have `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dia‌​lect`. Either change this to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and do not add the line `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` or delete the line `spring.jpa.database-platform` and add the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` line.

Comment: I added this line spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=true but still not working

Comment: Can you see my updated answer? I have modified your application.properties file and it should work. And no `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=true` wont work, you have to set a dialect not just `true` or `false`!

Comment: this is my application.properties: -    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/naijaconnectsdb
spring.datasource.username=naijaConnects
spring.datasource.password=Connects@2017
spring.datasource.name=naijaconnectsdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=null
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: Can you update your original question and add the application.properties file because in comments it is difficult to read it. And yes I can see an error in the last line of your comment: `spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`. Please post the application.properties in your question in order to be more readable

Comment: Check your last line it should be `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dia‌​lect ` not just `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dia‌​lect`

Comment: You are always making the same error my friend! `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect` No `MYSQL5Dialect` BUT `MySQL5Dialect`!!! Cant you just copy-paste the application.properties file contents from my answer? I have fixed it for you!

Comment: Hi pleft, Sorry I went to bed. spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect. added the line and still not working